# Using a third party library(libphonenumber) inside GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt

Is it possible to use a third party library in GWT ? In my case I want to use http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ inside a GWT/GXT application. As I lose focus of an element, the phone number should be formatted .

I know I can used this on the server side via an Ajax call. Is there any way I can add this at the client end?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no. But since there is a pure Javascript version, you could [roll your own GWT version](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/DesigningAPIWrappers) fairly easily with JSNI. While you wouldn't get the same ease-of-use as using their Java library, it beats making server calls for every keystroke.

Comment: @chis Thanks for the tip but the library I am trying to use is a Java library(A jar file) . I need to access this inside the client GWT client code but this library is not a GWT module.

Comment: @AravindA The problem is that some of the code in that jar can't be converted to javascript, and thus won't work on the client. You could certainly use server-side processing and RPCs to get it working, but it wouldn't be as responsive or as fast as a pure Javascript version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not directly. I have a project using 6-7 external jars. But, as Chris is pointing out, to use them you have to connect gwt client and server sides through RPC mechanism. And you will only be able to call .jar classes from server side.

In my case, I created a "lib" folder in my gwt project, added the .jar files, refreshed the project, right-clicked on all .jar files and then clicked "Build path" and "Add to build path". Like this you can use them on running time.

Comment: Thanks @Irene , but I'm looking for a client side approach . As I have mentioned , I know that I can use this on serer side but I wish to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a gwt module using libphonenumber java source code.
Check this link : [stackoverflow.com/q/25728158/1213961](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25728158/1213961)